# Group by with each result as a separate column pandas python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe similar to the sample below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([["USA", 1], ["Ireland", 1], ["USA", 0], ["Ireland", 0], ["UK", 1]], columns=['Country', 'Mental_Health_Problem'])
```

What I want to do is to count the number of occurrences of both 1 and 0 by country and group them by country. So I want column 1 to be the country name, column 2 to be the count of 0's by country and column 3 to be the count of 1's for the same country.

(I have seen similar questions asked but I can't find one which answers this)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```
result = df.groupby("Country")['Mental_Health_Problem']\
    .apply(pd.Series.value_counts)\
    .unstack(level=-1, fill_value=0)\
    .reset_index()

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
   Country  0  1
0  Ireland  1  1
1       UK  0  1
2      USA  1  1
```

Answer (score 1):

Lets Try `crosstab` to get group frequency which is what I think you are after.

```
pd.crosstab(df.Country,df.Mental_Health_Problem).reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)



    Country  0  1
0  Ireland  1  1
1       UK  0  1
2      USA  1  1
```